# Using Pip Install to Import a Python Library on Github

Tags: python, import, pip, package, google-colaboratory

as shown in the picture, I'm trying to use Pip install to import a library on a github repository. However, when I do this, I receive an "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" error. What am I doing wrong? Note that this is on Google Colab.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPCv2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/905ZY.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 1):

`pip install` is a console command, not a Python command. To issue commands to the console on Google Colab and other similar notebook environments, use an exclamation point at the beginning:

`!pip install git+https://...`